# How can a SharePoint SQL connection be set to query by the current login name?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, datasource

I have a SQL table that needs to be queried by the login name. So, using SharePoint designer I successfully created a database connection, but I can't use the properties exposed by **Profile** nor **Session** as input parameters because they are not supported (A dialog pops up with a message indicating this)

How else can I query a SQL datasource by using the current login?

-Edit

To create the data connection, proceed as follows

1. Open the data source library
2. Expand database connections and click on connect to a database
3. Enter the database settings
4. Select "specify custom Select, Update, Insert, and Delete"
5. Click on Edit Command
6. Add a parameter and select **Profile** and enter UserName as the property name

An error will follow stating that this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't give many details but I think you're looking for the LOGON_USER Server Variable: [Data View / Data Form: Parameters You Don’t Know About](http://blogs.msdn.com/spdsupport/archive/2008/07/25/data-view-data-form-parameters-you-don-t-know-about.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Kit, it would've been really nice if a SQL data source allowed for Server Variables as parameters.  It seems a DataView web part is needed to filter and pass information to other web parts.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I see what you mean now.. and unfortunately I don't have an answer for doing it using SPD. It seems this might call for a custom web part.